# Bidirectional binding ion Angular not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to do bi directional binding of 2 form control.

First Name

and

Second name.

In the fist case , I am trying to bind it with a class object
and in second case with  simple variable.

With Variable, it is working but with class it is not.

Please help.

Here is the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhkwmy

I am trying to check the value of the form by :

```
{{ ModelForm.value | json }}
```

in appcomponent.HTML

Comment: No idea what is going on here or what exactly you’re attempting to be honest. For starters, you never actually instantiate your class? If your goal is simply to demonstrate the live updating of the name at the top of the form.. there are way simpler (and better?) ways to accomplish that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

Making an object of the class was done wrong
Instead of :

```
public val: Fcc
```

It should have been :

```
val = new Fcc();
```